# Form error messages not working properly, form wont submit

Tags: php, forms, email, validation

I'm pretty new to form validation and processing, in fact, this is my first attempt, and I've created a simple contact form with required text fields, comments text area and two radio buttons. I've gone through many basic tuts and have put together script using PHP. The problem I have is that when i click submit if the form is unfilled, I am directed to a new page that has an error message saying i need to fill in my name. But if I fill in my name and click submit, I get the same message instead of the error message specified for the next field. I even get that message when all fields are filed in. Here is my code:

```
    <?php
    $myemail  = "ysjostar072@gmail.com";

    $name = check_input($_POST['name'], "Enter your name");
    $company = check_input($_POST['company'], "Enter your company name");
    $function = check_input($_POST['function'], "Provide an occassion");
    $address = check_input($_POST['address'], "Enter your address");
    $place = check_input($_POST['place'], "Enter your area code");
    $number = check_input($_POST['number'], "Enter your number");
    $mobile = check_input($_POST['mobile'], "Enter your mobile number");
    $email = check_input($_POST['email'], "Enter a valid E-Mail address");
    $client = check_input($_POST['client'], "Are you a client already? Please let us know");
    $method = check_input($_POST['method'], "Choose your preferred method of contact");
    $message = check_input($_POST['message'], "Enter your comments or description");
    $date = check_input($_POST['date'], "Tell us when your event takes place");
    $size = check_input($_POST['size'], "Tell us how big your presentation is going to be");


    $subject = "Client from website";
    $subject = striplashes($subject);

    if(isset($_POST['button-submit'])) {

    if (!isset($_REQUEST['email'])) {
        header( "Location: index.html" );
      }
      else {
        mail( "ysjostar072@gmail.com", "Feedback Form Results",
          $message, "From: $email" );
        header( "Location: thanks.html" );
      }

    } 

    if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
    {
        show_error("E-mail address not valid");
    }


    $enquiry = "Hello!

    Your contact form has been submitted by:

    Name: $name
    Company: $company
    Event: $function
    Address: $address
    Place: $place
    E-mail: $email
    Contact number: $number
    Mobile: $mobile
    Current client: $Client

    Comments: $message

    My exhibition is on $date
    Size: $size

    Please contact me $method



    End of message";


    mail($myemail, $subject, $enquiry);

    header('Location: thanks.html');
    exit();


    function check_input($data, $problem='')
    {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
        {
            show_error($problem);
        }
        return $data;
    }

    function show_error($myError)
    {
    ?>
        <html>
        <body>

        <b>Please correct the following error:</b><br />
        <?php echo $myError; ?>

        </body>
        </html>
    <?php
    exit();
    }
    ?>
```

Please help me out. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance :)

Here is the HTML form:

```
    <form id="contact" method="post" action="sendmail.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                        <ul>
                                        <li style="margin-bottom:15px; text-align:left"><label for="name">Vorname/Name*</label>
                                                                                                <input id="name" name="Name" type="text" value="" class="name-field" /></li>

                                        <li style="margin-bottom:15px; text-align:left"><label for="company">Firma*</label>
                                                                                                <input id="company" name="Company" type="text" value="" class="company-field" /></li>

                                        <li style="margin-bottom:15px; text-align:left"><label for="function">Funktion*</label>
                                                                                        <input id="function" name="Function" type="text" value="" class="function-field" /></li>

                                        <li style="margin-bottom:15px; text-align:left"><label for="address">Adresse*</label>
                                                                                        <input id="address" name="Address" type="text" value="" class="address-field" /></li>

                                        <li style="margin-bottom:15px; text-align:left"><label for="place">PLZ/Ort*</label>
                                                                                        <input id="place" name="Place" type="text" value="" class="place-field" /></li>

                                        <li style="margin-bottom:15px; text-align:left"><label for="number">Telefon*</label>
                                                                                        <input id="number" name="Number" type="text" value="" class="number-field" /></li>

                                        <li style="margin-bottom:15px; text-align:left"><label for="mobile">Mobiltelefon*</label>
                                                                                        <input id="mobile" name="Mobile" type="text" value="" class="mobile-field" /></li>

                                        <li style="margin-bottom:15px; text-align:left"><label for="email">E-Mail*</label>
                                                                                        <input id="email" name="Email" type="text" value="" class="email-field" /></li>




                                        <li style="margin-bottom:15px; text-align:left">Wir sind bereits Kunde*
                                                                                                                <input type="radio" name="Client" id="r1" value="Ja" />
                                                                                                                    <label for="r1">Ja</label>
                                                                                                                <input type="radio" name="Client" id="r2" value="Nein" />
                                                                                                                    <label for="r2">Nein</label>
                                        </li>



                                        <li style="margin-bottom:15px; text-align:left">Kontaktieren Sie uns*
                                                                                                            <input type="radio" name="method" id="r3" value="Per telefon" />
                                                                                                                    <label for="r3">Per telefon</label>
                                                                                                                <input type="radio" name="method" id="r4" value="Per e-mail" />
                                                                                                                    <label for="r4">Per e-mail</label>
                                        </li>

                                        <li style="margin-bottom:15px; text-align:left"><label for="message">Bemerkungen*</label>
                                                                                        <textarea id="message" name="Message" type="text" value="" class="message-field" ></textarea></li>

                                        <li style="margin-bottom:15px; text-align:left"><label for="date">Nächste Messe datum*</label>
                                                                                        <input id="date" name="Date" type="text" value="" class="date-field" /></li>

                                        <li style="margin-bottom:15px; text-align:left"><label for="size">Standgrösse m sq*</label>
                                                                                        <input id="size" name="Size" type="text" value="" class="size-field" /></li>

                                        <li style="margin-top:25px; margin-right:10px; text-align:left; color:#F00">*Diese Felder werden benötigt.</li>

                                        <input type="submit" class="button-submit" id="button-submit" value="Senden" name="button-submit" />

                                        </ul>
                                     </form>
```

Comment: How does the check_input function is called, I think we are missing some code here.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that this if `if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)` is always true - which makes me think that you don't get any value in `$_POST['name']` - put some messages and see what information you have there.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this code and it works on my side! try to utf8 encode your text, the form inputs name and so on...

```
<input type='text' name='name'>
<?php
$myemail  = "tresorunikin@gmail.com";

$name = check_input($_POST['name'], "Enter your name");
$company = check_input($_POST['company'], "Enter your company name");
$function = check_input($_POST['function'], "Provide an occassion");
$address = check_input($_POST['address'], "Enter your address");
$place = check_input($_POST['place'], "Enter your area code");
$number = check_input($_POST['number'], "Enter your number");
$mobile = check_input($_POST['mobile'], "Enter your mobile number");
$email = check_input($_POST['email'], "Enter a valid E-Mail address");
$client = check_input($_POST['client'], "Are you a client already? Please let us know");
$method = check_input($_POST['method'], "Choose your preferred method of contact");
$message = check_input($_POST['message'], "Enter your comments or description");
$date = check_input($_POST['date'], "Tell us when your event takes place");
$size = check_input($_POST['size'], "Tell us how big your presentation is going to be");


$subject = "Client from website";
$subject = striplashes($subject);

if(isset($_POST['button-submit'])) {

if (!isset($_REQUEST['email'])) {
    header( "Location: index.html" );
  }
  else {
    mail( "ysjostar072@gmail.com", "Feedback Form Results",
      $message, "From: $email" );
    header( "Location: thanks.html" );
  }

} 

if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
{
    show_error("E-mail address not valid");
}


$enquiry = "Hello!

Your contact form has been submitted by:

Name: $name
Company: $company
Event: $function
Address: $address
Place: $place
E-mail: $email
Contact number: $number
Mobile: $mobile
Current client: $Client

Comments: $message

My exhibition is on $date
Size: $size

Please contact me $method



End of message";


mail($myemail, $subject, $enquiry);

header('Location: thanks.html');
exit();


function check_input($data, $problem='')
{
    $data = trim($data);
    if (strlen($data) == 0)
    {
        show_error($problem);
    }
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}

function show_error($myError)
{
?>
    <html>
    <body>

    <b>Please correct the following error:</b><br />
    <?php echo $myError; ?>

    </body>
    </html>
<?php
exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I'm still having the problem... maybe the issue is in my from code?

Comment: I added the form in my original question